# How to combine the values in the first row of the matrix with the value in the next row?

Tags: python, numpy

I try to traverse the matrix and gradually chain the values according to the sequence given in the example below. First combine the first two values in the first line with the second value in the second line, then combine the first two values in the second line with the second value in the third line, and so on. Then, if it passes the last line, it returns to the beginning and takes the first three values and continues in the same way to the end of the matrix.I'm sorry, I'm new to the python

Example:

```
import numpy as np
np.array([[11,12,13,14],
          [21,22,23,24],
          [31,32,33,34],
          [41,42,43,44],
          [51,52,53,54]])
```

required output:

```
[11 12 22]
[21 22 32]
[31 32 42]
[41 42 52]

[11 12 13 23]
[21 22 23 33]
[31 32 33 43]
[41 42 43 53]
```

It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
arr = np.array([[11, 12, 13, 14],
                [21, 22, 23, 24],
                [31, 32, 33, 34],
                [41, 42, 43, 44],
                [51, 52, 53, 54]])

def func(arr, some_value = 2): # 2 or 3 in the example

    for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
        for j in range(some_value):
            print(arr[i][j], end=' ')

        print(arr[i+1][some_value-1])

func(arr, 2)
print()
func(arr, 3)
```

output:

```
[11 12 22]
[21 22 32]
[31 32 42]
[41 42 52]

[11 12 13 23]
[21 22 23 33]
[31 32 33 43]
[41 42 43 53]
```